# Bad output when building a histogram

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, histogram

I am having some issues building a histogram.

Here is my code:

```
distribution = dict()
count = 0
name = input("Enter file:")
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
    count = count + 1
    firstSplit = line.split()           # This gets me the line of text
    time = firstSplit[5]                # This gets me time - ex: 09:11:38
    # print(firstSplit[5])
    timeSplit = time.split(':')
    hr = timeSplit[1]                   # This gets me hrs - ex: 09

    # Gets me the histogram
    if hr not in distribution:
        distribution[hr[1]] = 1
    else:
        distribution[hr[1]] = distribution[hr[1]] + 1
    print(distribution)

# print(firstSplit[5])
```

I read the text in, and I split it to get the lines, done by `firstSplit`. This line of text includes a time stamp. I do a second split to get the time, done by `timeSplit`.

From here, I try to build the histogram by trying to see if the hour is in the dictionary, if it is, add one, if not, add the hour. But this is where it goes wrong. My output looks like:

[Example of Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PaX2.jpg)

Any advise or suggestions would be great!

Seán

Comment: I have found at least one of my issues. I was using hr[1] as an index, but it should have been hr[0]. Still getting bad output though.

Comment: I think I have this 90% done, I just need to order my hours now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect method to check if the hour is a key in the histogram. Here is the correct way to check:

```
if not (hr in list(distribution.keys()):
```

Also, you should be checking if a value is a key, then using the *same* value as the key that you create / add to. Therefore, the above will now be:

```
if not (hr[1] in list(distribution.keys()):
```

These two changes should fix your code and build you a great histogram!

---

**Note:** *Code is untested*